# How to make my command line work on files which have extention(.sh) and name like "weird.sh.sh.sh"

Tags: bash, command

I need to write a command line that searches for all file names that end with ".sh" (without quotation marks) in the current directory and all its sub-directories. It should display only the name of files without the extension .sh.
Here's my command script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -not -name "*.sh"  | sed -e 's/\..*$//'
```

Where's my mistake?
How can I change it to work with files like weird.sh.sh.sh with extention .sh
My command must print only name of all except files with .sh extention.
Example:

```
$>./my_find_sh | cat -e
file1$
file2$
file3$
$>
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `find -not -name '*.sh'` *excludes* anything that matches `*.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Using  **-not** will make the oposite, it will select all files that do not end with .sh

To also remove things like  ...sh.sh.sh you must use `(\.sh)*$` because `()*` repeats the pattern if it exists

```
find . -name "*.sh" | sed -E 's/(\.sh)*$//'
```

if you have

```
-rw-r--r--  1  test2.sh
-rw-r--r--  1  test3.sh
-rw-r--r--  1  test4.sh.sh.sh.sh
-rw-r--r--  1  text1.sh
```

and run

```
find . -name "*.sh" | sed -E 's/(\.sh)*$//'
```

you get

```
test2
test3
text1
test4
```

of isf you want only one time to remove the ".sh" then use this :

```
find . -name "*.sh" | sed -E 's/\.sh$//'
```

will output this :

```
test2
test3
text1
test4.sh.sh.sh
```

check the code

Comment: I need to display all files without ".sh" extention. Is it possible using commands:find,rev,cut,sed?

Comment: @Blazing_Sun have you tested the solution ?

Comment: It shouldn't remove "sh"

-rw-r--r--  1  test4.sh.sh.sh.sh
Output:
test4.sh.sh.sh

Comment: You talk very unclear. you want it to remove ony one ".sh" , not every ?

Comment: Yeah, only one.

Comment: Yes, it works as I needed. Thanks. But how to make it to display only name of files.

Answer (score 0):

I have a naming scheme for files, for this very reason.  I always put a plus sign (+) before any extension in a file name, so that I can use it as a seperator with cut.

```
echo test+.sh | cut -d'+' -f1
```

This will produce "test".